# rails credentials not fetching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, credentials

I created rails config/master.key and config/credentials.yml.enc via rails credentials:edit command

on rails console i'm able to fetch values but when i run rake db:migrate, i get this error:

```
invalid port number: "Rails.application.credentials.development[:port]"
Couldn't create 'Rails.application.credentials.development[:database]' database. Please check your configuration.
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: invalid port number: "Rails.application.credentials.development[:port]"
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/pg-1.1.4/lib/pg.rb:56:in `initialize'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/pg-1.1.4/lib/pg.rb:56:in `new'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/pg-1.1.4/lib/pg.rb:56:in `connect'
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:create
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

```
#config/environments/development.rb
config.require_master_key = true

#config/credentials.yml.enc
development:
  database: xxxxxxxx
  username: yyyyyyyy
  password: zzzzzzzz
  host: aaaaaaa.com
  port: 1234

# Used as the base secret for all MessageVerifiers in Rails, including the one protecting cookies.
secret_key_base: 1234567890

#config/database.yml
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: Rails.application.credentials.development[:database]
  username: Rails.application.credentials.development[:username]
  password: Rails.application.credentials.development[:password]
  host: Rails.application.credentials.development[:host]
  port: Rails.application.credentials.development[:port]

development:
  <<: *default
```

Comment: Could the 4 spaces used for indentation in the credentials file be the issue? YAML uses 2 spaces and it's non-forgiving about using any other amount (whitespace-sensitiive).

Comment: changed that to 2 spaces. Still same error (updated above original creds file). Thank you!

Comment: Try logging the actual value of `Rails.application.credentials.development[:port]` in the same exact migration. Could be, that the value is actually read from the credentials, but it's a wrong port number.

Comment: I did that. like said it works in rails console. the values are being fetched correctly.

Comment: I tried using dig: Rails.application.credentials.dig(:development, :port) but same error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks that problem in syntax

You need to use interpolation like this:

```
  database: <%= Rails.application.credentials.development[:database] %>
  username: <%= Rails.application.credentials.development[:username] %>
  password: <%= Rails.application.credentials.development[:password] %>
  host: <%= Rails.application.credentials.development[:host] %>
  port: <%=Rails.application.credentials.development[:port] %>
```