# Rails dotenv production issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dotenv

```
[ bin/setup ] [{"RAILS_ENV"=>"test"}, "bin/rails db:reset"] succeeded
[ bin/setup ] Dropping & recreating the test database
[ bin/setup ] Executing [{"RAILS_ENV"=>"production"}, "bin/rails db:reset"]
rails aborted!
ArgumentError: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this string with `bin/rails credentials:edit` (ArgumentError)

        raise ArgumentError, "Missing `secret_key_base` for '#{Rails.env}' environment, set this string with `bin/rails credentials:edit`"
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/home/mustdos/Ruby Stuff/MUPSA/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:reset => db:drop => db:load_config => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
[ bin/setup ] [{"RAILS_ENV"=>"production"}, "bin/rails db:reset"] failed
```

Hello all, I tried using dotenv with .env.testing .env.development and .env.production but I can't seem to get the .env.production running.

How should I solve this issue?

Comment: Yes, it's in the .env.production file

Comment: I followed a tutorial to ```rm config/database.yml config/credentials.yml.enc config/master.key ``` and avoid confusion with multiple sets of keys/environments

Comment: You need to add more details. Where is this occurring? How are you deploying? Where are you deploying to?

Comment: I've been reading it in "sustainable web development with rails by David Copeland". I saw the github page of dotenv and said I could just add .env.production and be good to go... Turns out there might be something missing.
I tried adding SECRET_KEY in .env.production since this is where my issue started, but no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Ruby on Rails documentation](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/security.html)

> In test and development applications get a secret_key_base derived from the app name. Other environments must use a random key present in config/credentials.yml.enc.

So as your error message suggests, we need to set a `secret_key_base`.

1. It can any random string so let's generate one randomly using `securerandom`. You can run this to get a random string of 64 characters.

```
require 'securerandom'
SecureRandom.hex(64)
```

2. Now, let's create and set it in our encrypted secrets. I use VSCode so my command for editing my secrets so my command will be like this.

```
EDITOR="code --wait" rails credentials:edit --environment production
```

That will open the decrypted state of the encrypted file that contains your secrets. It should be empty since you haven't set any before.
Set your `secret_key_base` like so:

```
secret_key_base: xxxxxxxx
other_secret: 123
```

3. Save and close the file. That will create you two files:

- `production.key` which the key that is used to decrypt your secrets encrypted file. That file contains sensible data and should not be public (not pushed to your Git repository). If you deploy your application somewhere, this should be set as an environment variable called `RAILS_MASTER_KEY`. This should be added to your `.gitignore` file.
- `production.yml.enc` which is the secrets encrypted file.

Now, you should be able to access your secrets like so in your code:

```
Rails.application.credentials.secret_key_base
Rails.application.credentials.other_secret
Rails.application.credentials.{secret_key}
```

4. And you should be able to perform `production` environment operation such as `rails console` or `rails db:migrate`.

PS: In your `development` environment, it is actually using a `secret_key_base` that is automatically generated in `tmp/development_secret.txt` if you didn't set any with the steps above.
Reference is [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.1.2/classes/Rails/Application.html#method-i-secret_key_base).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need dotenv to declare secret base

Deleting of `config/database.yml`, `config/credentials.yml.enc` `config/master.key` is also not good idea

You try to go opposite the system

Use built-in credentials. If you need to use different credentials for different environments - use it!

Regenerate credentials:

```
EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit
```

For production:

```
EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit --environment production
```

Double check, that you have in production credentials `secret_key_base`. If absent - add it manually

Also check that `config/credentials/*.key` and `config/master.key` are gitignored, all `*yml.enc` are not gitignored

For `database.yml` use ERB-syntax with credentials, [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57633370/10608621)